# Mongoid attribute seems to not be there, but I can query by it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Here's whats happening that I can display in the most succinct way possible:

```
Model.where(:flag => false).count
=> 6
Model.where(:flag => false).first.flag
=> nil
```

Some background: used to have an attribute field called flag on my model. Instead I changed it to `has_one flag` . I'm trying to run the migration except there's 6 records that have flag as `false` for some reason except when I find them by themselves, `flag` is nil.

My assumption is that when I actually run `.flag` by itself, it tries to query the `has_one` relationship. But when I run a `where`, it actually queries old records that still have the `field :flag` set on them. How can I fix this?

Comment: I added my answer below. I hope thats the real way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the way to do this is through `unset`

Here's a small snippet I found:

https://coderwall.com/p/wcx4pq/mongoid-remove-unnecessary-properties-from-documents